# Modeling atmospheric reentry with respect to the rotation of a planet and its atmosphere in a simulation

Tags: astrophysics, atmospheric-science, space-travel

I am creating a hard science fiction flight simulator. I am a civil engineering student, so its a little out of my area of study.

Currently I model air resistance on the velocity difference between a spaceship and the planet or moon in question. I do not currently take into account the spin of the planet.

I suspect that when calculating reentry speed I should be calculating the velocity difference between the possibly rotating atmosphere and the ship at that point in low orbit, not the velocity difference between the whole planet and the spacecraft. I am curious if the upper atmosphere rotates at the same rate as the atmosphere closer to surface. I've taken one fluid mechanics course, but it didn't get nearly this in depth. I suspect the atmosphere slows the higher you get up, but still rotates with earth rotation, but that is just my best guess.

I will be implementing the answer to this question in generalized formulas that apply to moons and planets with very different masses, radius and atmospheres, so general information that could apply to earth or any other natural satellite or planet would be helpful.

https://www.facebook.com/pages/Escape-Velocity-Hard-Science-Fiction-Indie-Game-Project/323567617834556

Comment: Generally, there are several different levels in the atmosphere that have significantly different wave speeds.  For instance, you know that wind higher than 80 km/hr (~50 mph) is relatively rare at sea level (except in the antarctic).  At higher altitudes, there are commonly winds exceeding several hundred mph, but the density is much lower so the effects will be different (drag depends upon density).  However, if you are re-entering at tens of thousands of mph, such differences in wind speed may not matter greatly (but that's just a knee-jerk guess).